# Rounded tabs focused border

Tags: tabs, javafx, focus, rounding

For a JavaFX application of mine I have specified that all tabs of my tab panes shall have rounded corners.

```
.tab {
    -fx-border-radius: 10 10 0 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 10 10 0 0;
}
```

Now, what else do I have to specify that the blue border which is displayed when the tab is focussed also has the same radius?
Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at modena.css file, for the selected tab pseudoclass, there is this rule for the border radius:

```
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-radius: 2, 1; /* looks sharper if outer border has a tighter radius (2 instead of 3) */
}
```

You just need to addapt it to your settings. For instance:

```
.tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-border-radius: 11 11 0 0, 10 10 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem so far although I find it rather bad practice by the makers of modena that you have to specify a value like this radius in slight variations in so many places. To my opinion one should have to specify this radius just in one place and the other values should be derived from that master radius.

Comment: Well, this is done for most of the colors as you say. You could make your own css implementation, though, and create as many variables as you need for other rules. But there're so many options, that it wouldn't be practical, in my opinion.

Comment: @mipa You could try to make use of something like [LESS](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/08/07/using-less-in-javafx/) to setup common variables.  However for it be truly useful in the manner you describe, you would probably want to also transcribe modena.css to be LESS based, which is a non-trivial task and as, Jose points out, may not be practical.